# FD_SET not putting the file descriptor in the set

Tags: c, client-server, file-descriptor

I am using the following code to set the value of a file descriptor 
`fd_set current_sockets, ready_sockets;`

`FD_SET(sock_fd, &current_sockets);`
In the above sock_fd is 3. And after the execution of this line I don't see this value 3 in 
current_sockets. In fact I see some weird set of values. What could be the reason for this ?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `fd_set current_sockets, ready_sockets;`, both of those variables are uninitialized. [`man 2 select`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) says this:

> ```
>    FD_ZERO()
>           This macro clears (removes all file descriptors from) set.
>           It should be employed as the first step in initializing a
>           file descriptor set.
> ```

But you skipped this non-optional step, so your FD sets are full of random garbage.

Also, the contents of the `fd_set` structure are unspecified, so you shouldn't expect to be able to make sense of them by any means other than using `FD_ISSET`.